# Running function before window has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wasn't sure how to correctly word the title, but here's what I have going on. I have two images in the body of the html.

```
<img src="http://www.narm.org.uk/home/images/Daylight%20design.jpg" id="b1" alt="day" />
<img src="http://www.aphoenix.ca/photoblog/photos/NighttimeColours.jpg" id="b2" alt="night" />
```

The corresponding css is as follow (basically makes one of them the background):

```
#b1, #b2 {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
window.onload = function() {
setBackground();
}

function setBackground() {
var back1 = $('#b1').hide();
var back2 = $('#b2').hide();
//setTimeout(function() {setBackground()}, 1000);
}
```

What currently happens now is that one image will display briefly because I"m waiting until the page has loaded to hide both the backgrounds. How would I go about hiding the backgrounds before the page has completely loaded?

Comment: `window.onload` will wait for all resources to be loaded. Do your stuff when the dom is [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to be manipulated.

Comment: Just run setBackground() without attaching it to onload?

Comment: Note that there's no need to assign back1 and back2, since you're not using those variables. You can just call .hide() without assigning it to anything.

Comment: Did joshft91 just advice hemself? `It looks like the ready function is what I'll need to work with here.` - joshft91

Comment: The reason I'm doing this is because eventually I"ll be checking the time when the page loads and setting a background based on that time.

Comment: Notice that in IE6 7 and 8 the domcontentloaded event fires late (right before onload), so you'll still see a flash in old ie using `.ready`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with css on your images:

```
display: none;
```

So, styles will be like:

```
#b1, #b2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: I had provided an answer but a commenter pointed out the problem with it. I support this answer instead. This way they'll default to hidden, then you can make them appear when you're ready for them.

Comment: I was doing this before but I had read that there are sometimes issues with using `display:none`.  I'll give this another shot and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [jQuery.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var back1 = $('#b1').hide();
    var back2 = $('#b2').hide();
});
```

---

The `window.onload` function is fired when all external sources is loaded (styles, scripts, images, etc..)

jQuery's `ready` method is fired when the DOM is ready.

[A little article about the difference](http://web.enavu.com/daily-tip/daily-tip-difference-between-document-ready-and-window-load-in-jquery/)

Comment: Won't that simply cause the same problem, by making the code wait for the document to be ready before it executes. If I read the question correctly, he wants the function to be called before the document is ready.

Comment: @FrankB I think it's a matter of misunderstanding. I think OP want's to modify the images before they are loaded and not before the DOM is ready. Think OP just isn't 100% clear about what he/she is asking.

Comment: You're right, and I've deleted my answer now that I see that.

Comment: The issue here is that the images could still be loaded before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Take the function out of the window.onload call, and move it to between two script tags at the top of the page. The browser reads from top to bottom, so it will execute the code as soon as it sees it.

so make your code look something like this:

```
<head>...
<script>
setBackground();
</script>
...</head>
```

Comment: That will not work. There will be no images in document at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to create a custom functions for this, you can have all your content hidden, once the page is ready .load() you hide you background then show the new background and the content

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to preload the images and keep them hidden until you need them.

Rather than JavaScript, css seems to be the way to go here. However if you use `display:none;` some browsers might decide to delay the image load. My suggestion is to move the images offscreen:

```
#b1, #b2 {
left: -9999px;
top: -9999px;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
}
```

[Update] Here is a test page for display:none:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/displayimg.html

It mentions that Opera will not load the images.